# security issues running a proxied app without ssl?

Tags: node.js, http-proxy, apache2.4

I have a nodejs app created using express to serve a page on my site. The app is then proxied by apache so that with the url

```
https://mycooldomain.com/folder
```

I have my node js app.

On Apache I have

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyPass /folder http://mycooldomain.com:4242
ProxyPassReverse /folder http://mycooldomain.com:4242
```

Node and Apache are currently on the same machine so I expect that using http is not an issue on this side.
Is it a concern while dealing with the end users? mycooldomain.com is properly secured with ssl but I don't want to create a security hole with this http proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I think while there is **only** the Apache server has access to your Express application, it's fine. HTTPS protocol secures data transferred between client and server, you have it already. The communication between your Apache server and your Express application, unless someone has access to your server, is invisible IMHO.

But there will be a problem when people can directly access your Express application without passing your Apache. You may need to add firewall rules to prevent it if this isn't the case yet.

Comment: the 4242 port is closed from outside, so that's not an issue. So you are telling me that the not encrypted trafic coming from express is always served as encripted by apache? There are no option where someone can leverage this http to https conversion?